# Update of Springframework-core in Maven is giving me a timeout

Tags: java, maven, repository

This is what it looks like:

```
artifact org.springframework:spring-core: checking for updates from glassfish-repository
WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact org.springframework:spring-core' could not be    retrieved from repository: glassfish-repository due to an error: Error transferring file:    Connection timed out
```

The glassfish-repository seems to not be reachable. I don't understand why Maven is trying to connect to a glassfish-rep. I thought it tries to reach the central-repository, which is available (I checked). Well, I think I don't really understand this remote-repository-management of maven. Maybe someone can help me out here?

Comment: several days before, I also found that the site maven.glashfish.org is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the `glassfish-repository` registered somewhere in your configuration, either in your pom.xml or ~/.m2/settings.xml.